# how to write test class for running user

Tags: unit-test

Below is my test class in salesforce apex:-

```
@isTest
public class Testopoffers{
    @isTest
    private static void testRun(){
        Contact c = new Contact(AccountId = '001g000000OPOr1',LastName = 'test');
        insert c;
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='OnlineForms User']; 
        User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='onlineforms@testorg.com', 
        EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',ContactId = c.id, 
        LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
        TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='onlineforms@testorg.com');
        System.runAs(u){
        System.debug('Current User: ' + UserInfo.getUserName());
        System.debug('Current User ID: ' + UserInfo.getUserId());
            dsmtOpOffersCntlr dopc = new dsmtOpOffersCntlr();
            String pageRef = dopc.updateDSMTracker().getUrl();
            System.assertEquals('/default/dsmtManageEnrollmentApplicationUser', pageRef);
        }
    }

}
```

And below is the class and function for which the above test class is for :-

```
global class dsmtOpOffersCntlr{

    public pagereference updateDSMTracker(){
       u.DSMTracker_Show_Help_Splash_Screen__c=true;
       update u;
       return null;
    }

    public dsmtOpOffersCntlr(){

        u =[Select DSMTracker_Show_Help_Splash_Screen__c  from User where id=:UserInfo.getUserId()];       

    }
}
```

The above test class is giving the following error in debug logs :-
System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

User is creating correctly for your information. 
Please can anybody give me correct syntax to write the test class for above class and method ?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What line is throwing the `NullPointerException` error?

Comment: Have a look at an answer I wrote a few months ago, it might be helpful http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/60329/how-to-make-static-initialization-considering-user-in-runas-in-test-class/60376#60376

Comment: You have to insert your user.  You create the User u, but do not insert it

Comment: String pageRef = dopc.updateDSMTracker().getUrl();  after this line the error is coming. I have inserted the user but still same error

Comment: It doesn't appear that the user record you've inserted has a DSMTracker_Show_Help_Splash_Screen__c value at the time of the select, so you're getting a Null return?  I could be wrong.  Why not set the value in the user insert during the test?

Answer (score 2):

The method below returns `null` in your code

```
public pagereference updateDSMTracker(){
   u.DSMTracker_Show_Help_Splash_Screen__c=true;
   update u;
   return null;
}
```

When the line below executes you are getting a `NullPointerException` because you are trying to call `getUrl()` on `null`

```
String pageRef = dopc.updateDSMTracker().getUrl();
```

Comment: I believe I just said this earlier, but that's exactly why you shouldn't use a PageReference return type if you don't intend to return a value. It avoids mistakes like this.